# Parsing xml into table but filtering by date

Tags: javascript, xml

I am a little stuck. I am creating a little bit of javascript which builds a table of past results. This works fine. However, I have the additional problem that I need to look at the date of the assessment being viewed (or written) and only return the last 5 results previous to this one.

The xml is created by the system and includes all results currently recorded against a client.
I hit upon the idea of setting up thisdate (the date of the assessment being viewed / written) and thatdate (the date of the value of the xml row currently being processed) but I can't quite get my head around doing this at the row level rather than at the cell level. The code below limits the date cells but not the result cells. Therefore i am getting this:-

| Assessment Date | Waterlow Score |
| --- | --- |
| 10 |  |
| 07/07/2021 | 24 |
| 06/07/2021 | 15 |

Any pointers greatly appreciated!

XML

```
  <PrevWL>
    <assessmentdate>08/07/2021</assessmentdate>
    <wltotal>10</wltotal>
  </PrevWL>
  <PrevWL>
    <assessmentdate>07/07/2021</assessmentdate>
    <wltotal>24</wltotal>
  </PrevWL>
  <PrevWL>
    <assessmentdate>06/07/2021</assessmentdate>
    <wltotal>15</wltotal>
  </PrevWL>
```

Javascript

```
GetControl("WLHistory").innerHTML = '<table style="border: 1px solid;border-collapse:collapse;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;" id="wlhistory"><tr style="border: 1px solid;border-collapse:collapse;"><td colspan="2" style="background-color:#aaaaaa;text-align:center;padding:0px 5px 0px 5px;">Waterlow Score History</td></tr><tr><td style="border: 1px solid;border-collapse:collapse;padding:0px 5px 0px 5px;">Assessment Date</td><td style="border: 1px solid;border-collapse:collapse;padding:0px 5px 0px 5px;">Waterlow Score</td></tr></table>'
  

var thisdate=GetControl("DateOfCarePlan").value
var thisdate=Date.parse(thisdate.toString().substr(6,4) + '-' + 
thisdate.toString().substr(3,2) + '-' + thisdate.toString().substr(0,2) + 'T00:00:00')

var table = document.getElementById("wlhistory");  
 var rows = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("PrevWL");
    for(var r=0;r<rows.length;r++){
        console.log("row "+r);

      tr = table.insertRow();
      tr.id='iteration_'+r;
        var vals = rows[r].childNodes;
        for(var x=0;x<vals.length;x++){
     
      value = vals[x].textContent;
      thatdate=Date.parse(value.toString().substr(6,4) + '-' + value.toString().substr(3,2) + '-' + value.toString().substr(0,2) + 'T00:00:00')
if(thatdate<thisdate || isNaN(thatdate)){
      console.log(value);
      td = tr.insertCell();
      td.id=x;
      td.setAttribute('value', value)
      td.setAttribute('style', 'border: 1px solid;border-collapse:collapse;padding:0px 5px 0px 5px;')
      td.textContent = value;}

}}
```

Comment: if row's children length are less than x, don't append (aka build the row before adding it to the table, rather than inserting then building.)

Comment: People - if you mark down a question at least post a comment to say why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this was what I came up with following a little bit of inspiration from Kevin B.
The length was a dead end, but I worked out that for vals=rows[r].childNodes, vals[0] is always the date attribute for each row.

I could then use this to get the date for the row and determine whether to build it or not.

```
GetControl("WLHistory").innerHTML = '<table style="border: 1px solid;border-collapse:collapse;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;" id="wlhistory"><tr style="border: 1px solid;border-collapse:collapse;"><td colspan="2" style="background-color:#aaaaaa;text-align:center;padding:0px 5px 0px 5px;">Waterlow Score History</td></tr><tr><td style="border: 1px solid;border-collapse:collapse;padding:0px 5px 0px 5px;">Assessment Date</td><td style="border: 1px solid;border-collapse:collapse;padding:0px 5px 0px 5px;">Waterlow Score</td></tr></table>'

var thisdate=GetControl("DateOfCarePlan").value
var thisdate=Date.parse(thisdate.toString().substr(6,4) + '-' + thisdate.toString().substr(3,2) + '-' + thisdate.toString().substr(0,2) + 'T00:00:00')

var table = document.getElementById("wlhistory");  
 var rows = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("PrevWL");
    for(var r=0;r<rows.length;r++){
        console.log("row "+r);

      tr = table.insertRow();
      tr.id='iteration_'+r;
      var vals = rows[r].childNodes;
      var value = vals[0].textContent
      thatdate=Date.parse(value.toString().substr(6,4) + '-' + value.toString().substr(3,2) + '-' + value.toString().substr(0,2) + 'T00:00:00')
if(thatdate<thisdate){

for(var x=0;x<vals.length;x++){
     
      value = vals[x].textContent;
      console.log(value);
      td = tr.insertCell();
      td.id=x;
      td.setAttribute('value', value)
      td.setAttribute('style', 'border: 1px solid;border-collapse:collapse;padding:0px 5px 0px 5px;')
      td.textContent = value;

}}}
```